# Integrating OpenFL app/library in standard native android app

Tags: android, flash, apk, haxe, openfl

I was wondering if it's possible to do one of the two:

1. Use OpenFL/Lime as a library inside my native app? AFAIK, to date this is a feature yet to be created??
2. Embed the generated lime/openfl app with my standard native android app, as an asset, or another special build, and invoke it at run time. This should, in general be possible, but how would I be able to bundle the app into another? Big question.

Yet, I do believe this would be to the benefits of many (!) if this question is resolved!

Comment: Is it possible at all to package two apps togather in one package? How hard is it in Android?